# Collection of bits to decimal conversion

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, binary

Requirement might be unique or outdated but last 2 hours of [google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=collection%20of%20binary%20bits%20to%20decimal%20in%20c%2B%2B&oq=collect&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59.3423j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8&safe=active) doesn't give the answered me.

I have one third path component which returns me a data in binary following is example:

```
long GetMyData()
{
    for(int index = 0; index < CollectionOfEntity.GetCount(); index++)
    {
        CString EntityName = CollectionOfEntity.GetAt(index);
        BOOL returnVal;
        //Get data from binary format
        hr = EntityInterface->GetDataInBit(EntityName, returnVal, FALSE);           
    }
    //Return all combine data into long.
}
```

I need to convert collection of "returnVal" bool value to "long".

Following is exception:

- I don't want to convert binary data into string and then binary string to decimal. this will created huge delay in my process execution.

Comment: Why is it tagged [Tag:C]?

Comment: @YSC Solution in C also accepted.

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade What about shifting and or-ing `returnVal` to the final desired `long` result? Your question is a bit unclear about the expected output.

Comment: If you want a solution working in both languages, how about not requiring a C++-only-function as shown in your question?

Comment: @cpp_learner Since final value should in long hence return type of function cannot change

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade `Solution in C also accepted ... I want solution in one language only.` ... If you don't even know what you want, how should we know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this solution?

```
long GetMyData() {
    long result = 0;
    for(int index = 0; index < CollectionOfEntity.GetCount(); index++) {
        CString EntityName = CollectionOfEntity.GetAt(index);
        BOOL returnVal;
        //Get data from binary format
        hr = EntityInterface->GetDataInBit(EntityName, returnVal, FALSE);      
        result |= returnVal << index; // <<<<<<<<<
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade Sure, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are getting the bits lowest first.

Just accumulate the answer, shifting in each new bit.

You can do this with either arithmetic or logical operators. Logical operators are cleaner, but arithmetic may be easier for you to read and maintain.

In both cases, before the loop have:

`long result = 0;`

Then, inside the loop, after you have returnVal, do either:

`result = result*2 + (returnVal? 1 : 0);`

or

`result = result<<1 | (returnVal? 1 : 0);`

Once you understand this, you can make the code cleaner (but less readable to a novice) in two ways:

- Remove the parenthesis around the final term. They are not needed.
- Replace the `? .. :` operator with a cast.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have more than the size of a long of bits and its in the correct order.
Something like this might work (untested).

```
long GetMyData()
{
    long res = 0;
    for(int index = 0; index < CollectionOfEntity.GetCount(); index++)
    {
        CString EntityName = CollectionOfEntity.GetAt(index);
        BOOL returnVal;
        //Get data from binary format
        hr = EntityInterface->GetDataInBit(EntityName, returnVal, FALSE);           
        res |= (returnVal << index);
    }
    //Return all combine data into long.
    return res;
}
```